# Python Dict vs List for adding unique element only

Tags: python, coding-style

In order to achieve an iterable of unique elements, is [2] acceptable?

```
# [1]
if element not in list:
    list.append(element)

# [2]
dict[element] = None # value doesn't matter
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) as your data structure.

List is not good performance wise, checking if the element is in a list takes linear time. The longer the list the slower it gets.

Set has constant look up time. Dictionary does too, but you don't need key-value pairs, so  it's more elegant to do:

```
s = set()
s.add(element)
```

than

```
s = {}
s[element] = None
```

Plus you get all the nice set operations, like union, intersection, etc. [See the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).